# how to display two row of database value in textfield when user select one value from drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu, textfield

**When a user select the name using drop down list,the stock and price text field should automatically be filled.But it wont.**

**This is the code**

```
<form action="insertout.php" method="post">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="116">Medicine name</td>
<td width="221">
<center>:
<select name="name" id="name">
<option>--- Choose Medicine ---</option>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("arie");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabelmedicine ORDER BY name ASC ");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo '<option     value="'.$row['price'].' && '.$row['price'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
}
?>
</select >
</center>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p align="center">:<input type="text" name="price" id="price"value="<?php echo ('priceperunit'); ?>" onClick="checkprice()">
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Stock</p>
</td>
<td>
<p align="center">:<input type="text" name="stock" id="stock"value="<?php echo ('stock'); ?>" onClick="checkprice()">
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<script>
var select = document.getElementById('name');
var input = document.getElementById('price');
var input = document.getElementById('stock');
select.onchange = function(){
    input.value = select.value;
}
</script>
```

**i hope u guys can help.i've spent a week just to figured out the code.**

Comment: You're assigning the var `input` twice with two different values and then using it only once. Can I suggest you make a jsFiddle of this issue?

Comment: database connection? Where?

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("arie");

Comment: You're trying to do this without an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) routine? Where is the `checkprice()` script?

Comment: First: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead.. Second: Check this out for // [Correct way to connect to a mysql database in php](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm) //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code, below are some notes

> Avoid using the Keywords like "name" in select box
>   Price and Stock Input element attribute are does not have spaced properly.
>   Avoid using Mysql_connect and start use PDO / MySQLi
>   Avoid presentational tags and start use css to acheive it like "text-align:center"

`Currently its working as you expected without Ajax and its a quick workaround, I have added the value in a comma separated the both value by split function.`

```
<form action="insertout.php" method="post">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="116">Medicine name</td>
<td width="221">
<center>:
<select name="name" id="name">
<option>--- Choose Medicine ---</option>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("arie");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabelmedicine ORDER BY name ASC ");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
// echo '<option     value="'.$row['price'].' && '.$row['price'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
$option_value = $row['price'] . ',' . $row['stock'];
echo '<option value="'.$option_value.'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
}
?>
</select >
</center>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Price</p>
</td>
<td>
<p align="center">:<input type="text" name="price" id="price"value="<?php echo ('priceperunit'); ?>" onClick="checkprice()">
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Stock</p>
</td>
<td>
<p align="center">:<input type="text" name="stock" id="stock"value="<?php echo ('stock'); ?>" onClick="checkprice()">
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<script>
var select = document.getElementById('name');
//var input = document.getElementById('price');
//var input = document.getElementById('stock');
var price = document.getElementById('price');
var stock = document.getElementById('stock');
select.onchange = function(){
    // input.value = select.value;
    var price_stock = select.value.split(',');
    price.value = price_stock[0];
    stock.value = price_stock[1];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.......

*Main File*

```
<?php
$medOptions = "";
mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db( "arie");
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM tabelmedicine ORDER BY name ASC ");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) !=0 ) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $medOptions .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>\n';
    }
}
?>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="label" width="55%">Medicine name</td>
            <td width="45%">
                <select name="med" id="med">
                    <option disabled="true" selected="true">--- Choose Medicine ---</option>
                    <?=$medOptions;?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="price" readonly="true" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Stock</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="stock" readonly="true" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

*CSS*

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
td {
    text-align:center;
}
.label {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

*Javascript*

```
var select = document.getElementById('med');
// INSERT AJAX ROUTINE TO RETRIEVE PRICE AND STOCK LEVEL
var medPrice = document.getElementById('price');
var medStock = document.getElementById('stock');
select.onchange = function () {
    medPrice.value = response.price;
    medStock.value = response.stock;
};
```

Comment: This gives you a GREAT foundation for your project. All you need to do is read up on AJAX routines... write one that grabs the correct price and stock level based on the selected medicine and you should be in great shape. You may also want to consider learning `jQuery` which gives you much more flexibility than vanilla Javascript.